# Python - Comments at Start of Lines

Tags: python, auto-indent

I've inherited some python 2.7 code that has commented out sections of code at the beginning of each line which is driving my crazy.  The code is separated over several files and is >50k lines total, so I'm looking for a way to automatically correct this.  Not all comments are at the start of the lines, but some are.  I've tried reindent and autopep8, but neither of them would fix this issue.  Here is an example:

```
def test_function():
    a = 1

# There are comments that are not indented!
# Usually with commented out code like this:
#    c = 5
#    if c > a:
#        a = c

    b = 5
    return a*b
print(test_function())
```

Sometimes the comments are at the start of the line even though the indent level is 4 or 5 levels deep.  Ideally the above would be converted to below.  Note how this involves adjusting the white space before *and* after the comment of the code lines to make them commented the way they should have been.  That would be ideal, but I'd even be a lot happier to have it just add the white space at the start but not adjust it after the comment, which is probably a lot easier.

```
def test_function():
    a = 1

    # There are comments that are not indented!
    # Usually with commented out code like this:
    # c = 5
    # if c > a:
    #     a = c

    b = 5
    return a*b
print(test_function())
```

Does anyone know if there is already some library that can do this before I go and try to create something myself?

Comment: if you remove just `#` at the start, the indentation is all right with your first example. If you do this on the second example it destroys the program.

Comment: That looks more like abandoned code. It also looks like someone has not used version control. Is it covered by tests?

Comment: In the second example, you would remove "# " from the code lines (remove # and a space).  This keeps it pep8 compliant, which I generally adhere to.  It is just as easy to remove "# " from the start of lines as it is "#".

Comment: Yes, it is abandoned code and I plan to clean it up, but I need to try to understand why the code was abandoned and clean it up (in due time).  The code is not in good shape right now and it is not version controlled.  I also plan to move it to a git repository when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together somewhat naive `awk` script that should be able to indent your comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
    last_indent=0
}

{
    indent=match($0, /[^ ]/) - 1
    if (indent < 0) indent = 0
    comment=0
}

/^#/{
    comment=1
    if (last_indent > 0) {
        indent_str = sprintf("%*s", last_indent, " ")
        $0 = indent_str $0
    }
}

{
    print
    if (length($0) && ! comment) last_indent=indent
}
```

Running it with:

```
$ cat src.py | ./reindent.awk
```

It should (it does so for your example file) print the input python file with extra spaces corresponding to current block prepended to the comments.

I've considered your extra request for the code in the comment to be adjust, but that is extremely non-trivial as the script would actually have to have decent level of understanding of what it's processing.

Needless to say, comment should in most cases be just dropped and leaving it around is not a very tidy practice at least since we have version control systems for sources (so early 70's).

---

In a simple case as the example, this may perhaps even succeed indenting code in comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
    last_indent=0
    commented_code_indent = 0
}

{
    indent=match($0, /[^ ]/) - 1
    if (indent < 0) indent = 0
    comment=0
}

/^#/{
    comment=1
    if (last_indent > 0) {
        indent_str = sprintf("%*s", last_indent, " ")
    stripped = length($0)
    sub(/#  +/, "# ")
    stripped -= length($0)
    if (stripped > 0 && ! commented_code_indent) commented_code_indent = stripped
    if (commented_code_indent > 0) {
       indent_in_comment = stripped - commented_code_indent
       if (indent_in_comment > 0) {
           comment_indent_str = sprintf("%*s", indent_in_comment, " ")
           sub(/# /, "# " comment_indent_str)
       }
        }
    $0 = indent_str $0
    }
}

{
    print
    if (length($0) && ! comment) last_indent=indent
    if (! comment) commented_code_indent = 0
}
```

And yes, looking at it now, there could have been easier choices then awk. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I'm in front of the code again.  Yes, I agree that the commented out code should be removed and it should be version controlled instead.  I plan to do that, but at the moment I'm just trying to wrap my hands around it.

Answer (score 0):

This indents lines that start with `#` to match the same level of indentation as the next non-comment line:

```
import sys

def remove_excess_space(comments):
    """Remove excess whitespace after #"""
    excess = 0
    for line in comments:
        stripped = line.lstrip('#').lstrip()
        if excess == 0:
            excess = len(line) - len(stripped) - len('# ')
        if excess > 0:
            line = '#{}'.format(line[1 + excess:])
        yield line

def fix(filename):
    indentation = 0
    comments = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                comments.append(line)
            else:
                stripped = line.lstrip()                
                if stripped and not stripped.startswith('#'):
                    # I'm assuming indentation is done with spaces, not tabs
                    indentation = len(line) - len(stripped)

                if comments:
                    # indent the comments using the same indenation as the next non-comment line
                    print(''.join(['{}{}'.format(' '*indentation, line)
                                   for line in remove_excess_space(comments)]), end='')
                    comments = []                    
                print(line, end='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    fix(filename)
```

If we call the this `indent_comments.py` then running:

```
indent_comments.py /path/to/script.py
```

prints

```
def test_function():
    a = 1

    # There are comments that are not indented!
    # Usually with commented out code like this:
    # c = 5
    # if c > a:
    #     a = c

    b = 5
    return a*b
print(test_function())
```

---

Note that there are corner cases where this script screws up. For example,
not every line that starts with `#` is necessarily a comment:

```
print('''\
# This is not 
    a comment
''')
```

would become

```
print('''\
    # This is not 
    a comment
''')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out when I'm in front of the code again.  Thanks for the warnings on the corner cases too.